# ggplot, use both vjust and hjust for the same graph, how to code this?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use both vjust and hjust in ggplot, change direction of the title both horizontally and vertically. This code doesn't work. How do I accomplish this? Thanks!

```
theme(plot.title =element_text(hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this by using two lines:

```
theme(plot.title =element_text(hjust=0.5)) +
theme(plot.title =element_text(vjust=0.5))
```